# OpenID Connect authentication provider for legacy user management?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, identity

We have a self-developed proprietary user management and self-developed Single Sign-on. (OpenID Connect wasn't born at that time)
Our authentication server and our thick clients are in a private network, without internet access.
The task is to integrate a third-party thick client - its users should authenticate against our existing authentication server.
The general idea is to use an existing future-oriented framework which offers a standard authentication interface (like Keycloak?) and implement our own OpenID Connect authentication provider (or User storage SPI for keycloack).
Is the way with keycloack and User storage SPI recommendable or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, this is a good choice for meeting your immediate requirements:

- External client uses a modern OpenID Connect flow - eg OIDC for desktop apps
- It connects to an Authorization Server with support for standards based endpoints
- Authorization Server has extensible support for data sources and can potentially reach out to your existing user data source

As an example, Curity, where I work, supports [multiple data sources](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/data-sources/index.html) and there is a [free community edition](https://curity.io/product/community) if useful.

Any provider that meets the same requirements would be fine though - and I've heard some good things about Keycloak.

**LONGER TERM**

It makes sense to then gradually update other apps to use modern OAuth and OIDC behaviour.

At a suitable point it is worth making the Authorization Server the only place from which Personally Identifiable user data is accessed, and moving the storage there. See this [data privacy article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/privacy-and-gdpr/) for some advantages of this.

Comment: Do you have an example for clean OIDC for desktop apps solution? Google finds only workarounds, like embedded browsing in the desktop apps..

Comment: Desktop is a tricky flow due to shelling out to the system browser - but I have a couple blog posts for a [Sample Electron App](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/) that may help you to understand issues. You can download and run samples if it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for Keycloak User Storage SPI approach. Recently implemented this for a project and it is working pretty well. For any existing user-database I highly recommend it.

I found some example source on github that you could look at (although needed some modification to run it):
https://github.com/mfandre/KeycloakSPI

I have also written an article summarizing my findings working with Keycloak in case you're interested in other features:
https://dev.to/kayesislam/keycloak-as-oidc-provider-42ip

It's extremely customisable.